# Is there a way to check if a WebView content is visible to user?

Tags: android, android-widget

In my application I need to show a progress dialog when downloading and loading content to WebView. I know about the `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` methods, it works, however, there is a few seconds of delay between the onPageFinished call and the time the content is actually visible on the screen.

Is there a way to dismiss the progress dialog when the content is really visible, not only loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a [PictureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html) to your webview.  Note that this is deprecated, but as far as I know there is no actual replacement provided by Android at this time.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer not to use deprecated methods but it seems I don't have a choice...

Answer (score 1):

From API level 23 you can use onPageCommitVisible.

```
@Override
public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
    // There you go.

}
```

Unfortunately I have not found any way to use it on lower API levels.